# Clearing arraylist also clears object arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So basically I have code that looks like this

```
supersetRowModel.setExerciseModelList(exerciseModelList);
exerciseModelList.clear();
```

My getter and setter for this class

```
 public void setExerciseModelList(List<ExerciseModel> exerciseModelList){
    this.exerciseModelList = exerciseModelList;
}

public List<ExerciseModel> getExerciseModelList(){
    return exerciseModelList;
}
```

Whenever I call getExerciseModelList() right after I clear the array list, it returns a list with size 0. I have checked and made sure that exerciseModelList is not size 0. This is confusing me, since clearing exerciseModelList should not affect the objects arraylist since it is already set, right?

Comment: Just do `exerciseModelList = new ArrayList<>();` instead of clearing it.

Comment: Works, thanks. But why wouldn't my method work?

Comment: Because your assumption is wrong. Both references are pointing to the same list.

Comment: That makes sense now.